# rename() only works for directory that program is running in?

Tags: c, rename

I am trying to rename a bunch of files in a user specified directory, but it only seems to be working when the user specifies the directory that the program is running from. For example, when running from the command line:

`./a.out . "NewName.txt"` will work, while

`./a.out .. "NewName.txt"` will not work. Is there a reason for this? It's on Linux, by the way.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char* dirpath = argv[1];
  char* newName = argv[2];

  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir(dirpath);
  if (d){
     while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
        char* filename = dir->d_name;
        if (rename(filename,newName) == 0){
           printf("Renaming %s -> %s\n",filename,newName);               
        } else {
           printf("Could not rename %s\n",filename);
        }
     }
   }
   closedir(d);
}
```

I have also tried (while running the program from outside of Desktop):

```
 if (rename("~/Desktop/test.txt","~/Desktop/test2.txt") == 0){
    printf("Renaming %s -> %s\n",filename,newName);               
 } else {
    printf("Could not rename %s\n",filename);
 }
```

and it still fails.

Comment: Doesn't this program take every file in the directory and rename it to the same name? Destroying all files except for one?

Comment: You can check the errno to see why rename failed. http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename

Comment: Yeah, in the actual program I have unique file names being generated. I have simplified it here. The problem persists though, even with unique file names.

Comment: You definitely need to check the error code. *Always* check the error codes. It is a habit that will keep you away from many mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `readdir()` is reading file names from the other directory, your program's current directory is still in a different location.  Unless you prefix the source file name with the path to the directory (and the destination file name too) you're trying to rename non-existent files in the current directory, in general.

In pseudo-code:

```
dir = opendir(remote_directory)
foreach name from dir
    rename "remote_directory/name" to "remote_directory/othername"
end for
```

Note that the pseudo-code works if 'remote_directory' happens to be `.`, the current directory; you don't need to special-case that code.

Comment: I have edited my question to add in something that I have tried, which is what I believe you are suggesting, although it still fails to rename.

Comment: Notes on the updated question: The `~` convention works in shells because shells expand `~` before calling the (C code in) commands, which in turn invoke the system calls underlying the `rename()` function.  You can't use the `~` notation (or environment variables) in a C program without doing the expansion yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The old argument points to the pathname of the file to be renamed. 
>       The new argument points to the new pathname of the file. 
>       **If the new argument does not resolve to an existing directory entry for a 
>       file of type directory and the new argument contains at least one non-`<slash>`
>       character and ends with one or more trailing `<slash>` characters after all symbolic 
>       links have been processed, `rename()` shall fail**

Looks like you're not referring to an existing element when you use any path other than '.', which is likely why it's failing.

Check the specific errno value to see why.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your main problem is that the result from `readdir` is just the filename. It doesn't include the directory. You need to paste the directory name and the filename from `dir->d_name` together in your program.