# Manage files and folders C

Tags: c, directory

I need to work with directories in a C program... The directory will be a parameter, I need to check all the files in the folder, if one of these files is a folder, I need to access it, also, I need to go back in the directories, i.e. "." and "..".

I'm using the library `<dirent.h>`, and right now I only can show all the content in the folder where I'm running the program (i.e. program.c, folder1, etc.). If I use something like "Desktop" as the parameter, it will show the error saying:

> Couldn't open the directory: No such file or directory.

Can you tell me how to do this?

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;     

    dp = opendir (argv[1]);
    if (dp != NULL){
        while (ep = readdir (dp))
        puts (ep->d_name);

        (void) closedir (dp);

        perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
xx@xfx  gcc e.c -o hola
xx@xfx ~/Desktop $ ./hola ./

hola
10475718_921955664486299_2309306989404354546_n.jpg
practica 4.tar.gz
h.c
pro
two-type-of-programmers-funny-jokes.png
as.c
a.c
prac 4
hol
Pr.hs
ej.c
du.c
.
tar
thats-racist-gif-1.gif
pract.
pract.c
e.c
prac.c
pract.c
..
Lab files #2
ejer1.c
music.pls
Lab files  #4
ho2.c
dir2
ejero1.c
t
Mate
Couldn't open the directory: Success
```

Comment: Please give a minimal but complete example of code for what you currently do.

Comment: I hesitate to close this as a duplicate of [`rename()` only works for directory that program is running in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744354/rename-only-works-for-directory-that-program-is-running-in/), but the underlying issue is exactly the same.  You have to prefix the names returned by `readdir()` with the path of the directory that you are scanning.

Comment: Note that your code unconditionally prints the 'error' message, too.  That message has no significance whatsoever.

Comment: Your call to `perror` happens _only if_ the call to `opendir` has succeeded.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your error handling is not placed correctly. The perror function is called outside the if statement, so it will always execute, regardless of whether the directory was successfully opened or not.

Here's a modified version of your code with improved error handling:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <directory>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;

    // Open the directory
    dp = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (dp != NULL) {
        // Read and display directory contents
        while ((ep = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
            puts(ep->d_name);
        }

        // Close the directory
        (void)closedir(dp);
    } else {
        // Print an error message if the directory couldn't be opened
        perror("Couldn't open the directory");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```